# I want to implement a video file on my Webpage (Wordpress) and making it responsive in terms of file size, to decrease loading times

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-video

I'm looking for the best way to embed a video file on my website.
What do i have to consider to make it fast?
Do i have to load up different video files (size and format) and let e.g. JS pick the right one depending on screen-size? Or is the browser doing this automatically?
Do you have some example code lines for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the video tag without a source, you can then inject the source based on the screen size (e.g. 720p for smaller screens 1080p for bigger screens). Of course, this means you have to create 'x' versions of the video (one for each screen size).

Another approach is to do video streaming.  You'll need a JavaScript player - but just like Netflix, you can have multiple sizes and bitrates, and the player will adjust the video playback on each device based on screen size and network speed. One huge advantage here is that it can adjust during playback to a different version to ensure that the video continues to pay.

There are services that will do this for you - just upload the video, and you'll get a link for the player that you can embed on your page - [api.video](https://api.video) is one.